# jQuery Smoothdivscroll ajax intermittent issues

Tags: jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

I'm experiencing an intermittent issue with the smoothdivscroll plugin. I have noticed that occasionally when I load the page, only the first image would show up and it would just be stationary. Sometimes(after a few refreshes) all the images would load and start scrolling. I have  inspected the response from ajaxContent.php and the fragment response seems to be correct.

I am currently using the following example code:

```
$("#div").smoothDivScroll({
    autoScrollingMode: "always", 
    autoScrollingDirection: "endlessloopleft", 
    autoScrollingStep: 1, 
    autoScrollingInterval: 15, 
    ajaxContentURL: "ajaxContent.php"
});
```

what ajaxContent.php does it that it returns page fragments with a div with an image source, similar to the example at http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/lab.html with the "Replace content with demo html content" turned on. The image src is actually a full path to an image at an external site, something like

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg">.
```

Example of a fragment returned:

```
<div class="contentBox">
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg">
</div>
<div class="contentBox">
<img src="http://example2.com/image2.jpg">
</div>
```

I have then also tried the demo example which seems to work quite well, could slow loading of images from the external sites cause the plugin to work incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could be caused by slow loading of images and/or by some problem with the CSS of the div with the class "contentBox" that makes it difficult for the plugin to calculate the total width of all the elements in the scrollable area.

When Smooth Div Scroll initiates it checks if there is an ajaxContentURL specified. If so, it loads the HTML-content from that URL and directly after it recalculates the width of the scrollable area. When it recalculates the width of the scrollable area it looks at the width of the direct child elements, in your case the div's with the class "contentBox". If these div's don't have a fixed width specified in the CSS **and** some/all of the images have not been fully loaded Smooth Div Scroll will calculate the total width of all the elements wrong.

If all images are the same width you could try setting a fixed width for the "contentBox"-divs. Another thing you could try is to temporarily strip away the wrapper div's and just load HTML with image-tags.